# Find placeholder and other tensors in remote graph

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running a distributed graph in a TensorFlow cluster, and wish to re-connect with this from a client as part of a prediction service. The only way I've found so far to make this work is via queues for the client's input and output using `shared_name`.

In principle named variables could be used for this as well, but is there any other way, using e.g. placeholders?

I've tried exploring the graph from the client's session but it only seems to contain nodes added by the client itself.